# Плавная заливка текста через fill

Tags: css, css3, анимация, sass, css-animation

Как залить текст через `fill` плавно?

В этом коде текст заливается цветом резко, когда анимация доходит до 90%, как залить его вместе с анимацией?

Вот код самой анимации:

```
.text-copy {
  fill: none;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-name:stroke-offset;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;

  stroke: #FDF590 ;
  stroke-dasharray: 7% 28%;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  }

  .text-copy:nth-child(1) {
    stroke: #F3D881  ;
    stroke-dashoffset: 7%; }
  .text-copy:nth-child(2) {
    stroke: #F3D881  ;
    stroke-dashoffset: 14%; }
  .text-copy:nth-child(3) {
    stroke: #F3D881  ;
    stroke-dashoffset: 21%; }
  .text-copy:nth-child(4) {
    stroke: #F3D881  ;
    stroke-dashoffset: 28%; }
  .text-copy:nth-child(5) {
    stroke-dashoffset: 35%; }

@keyframes stroke-offset {
  90% {
    fill:#F3D881  ;
    stroke-dashoffset: 35%;
    stroke-dasharray: 87.5%; } }
```

Знаю что есть transition и прочее, как его применить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо задать начальный цвет для `fill`, например transparent.

```css
.text-copy {
  fill: transparent;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-name:stroke-offset;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;

  stroke: #FDF590;
  stroke-dasharray: 7% 28%;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

  .text-copy:nth-child(1) {
    stroke: #F3D881  ;
    stroke-dashoffset: 7%; }
  .text-copy:nth-child(2) {
    stroke: #F3D881  ;
    stroke-dashoffset: 14%; }
  .text-copy:nth-child(3) {
    stroke: #F3D881  ;
    stroke-dashoffset: 21%; }
  .text-copy:nth-child(4) {
    stroke: #F3D881  ;
    stroke-dashoffset: 28%; }
  .text-copy:nth-child(5) {
    stroke-dashoffset: 35%; }

@keyframes stroke-offset {
  90% {
    fill: #F3D881;
    stroke-dashoffset: 35%;
    stroke-dasharray: 87.5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class=text-copy>
  <rect width="100" height="100" />
</svg>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, разобрался уже )